# Set Validation Rules for Your collection Schema on mongo db compass not working

Tags: database, mongodb, validation, nosql, mongodb-compass

I have a collection (i.e insurance)  in Mongo DB. The database is present in a cloud server. I am accessing the database through Mongo Db compass. When trying to add a validation rule on insurance collection.
[image]

No error is showing on submit.
[image]

No sure what is happening. any help is much appreciated.Thanks